# Setting pyplot 3D shade direction

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib bar3d(),
Is there a way to choose which face the shade falls onto?

I wanted to keep the shade for a better perspective, however the top of the bars are always shaded. This makes text on the top difficult to see.

Is there a way to change where the shades are, for example, swap the shaded/unshaded region?
I checked the LightSource option but it seems to apply to colormap and wasn't straight-forward as to how I can use it with bar3d.

Your help is appreciated.
[image: Example Plot]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a complete solution, but a way to side-step it.

Basically, you can assign the color to each face, as you then guess, you can just assign a darker color to the face where you want to have the shade falling onto.

For example, 
This is the original vector for assigning the color which, with shade="True", it gives the figure above:

```
cs0=['lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00','w',
'w','lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00',
'#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED','w',
'w','#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED',
'#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey','w',
'w','#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey']
```

Now I have to change it to a vector of 6 times the length, and every 6 elements in a row describe 1 bar for the 6 faces (see doc). In particular, I want the shade to fall on just the right side of the bars from this view angle, so I can edit only the three corresponding block, then put them together into a single vector, which look like:

```
cs1=['lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00','w',
'w','lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00',
'#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED','w',
'w','#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED',
'#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey','w',
'w','#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey']

#top
cs2=['lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00','w',
'w','lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00',
'#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED','w',
'w','#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED',
'#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey','w',
'w','#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey']

# left
cs3=['lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00','w',
'w','lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00',
'#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED','w',
'w','#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED',
'#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey','w',
'w','#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey']

cs4=['lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00','w',
'w','lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00',
'#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED','w',
'w','#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED',
'#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey','w',
'w','#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey']

cs5=['lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00','w',
'w','lightgrey','w','#FF8000','w','#66CD00',
'#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED','w',
'w','#FF8000','w','lightgrey','w','#6495ED',
'#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey','w',
'w','#66CD00','w','#6495ED','w','lightgrey']

# right
cs6=['grey','w','#CD3700','w','#458B00','w',
'w','grey','w','#CD3700','w','#458B00',
'#CD3700','w','grey','w','#104E8B','w',
'w','#CD3700','w','grey','w','#104E8B',
'#458B00','w','#104E8B','w','grey','w',
'w','#458B00','w','#104E8B','w','grey']

cs=cs0*6

cs[0::6]=cs1
cs[1::6]=cs2
cs[2::6]=cs3
cs[3::6]=cs4
cs[4::6]=cs5
cs[5::6]=cs6
```

Comment: How do the cs object fit with the rest of your code?  i.e., could you show all of the code with your working example

Comment: Sure, this is one example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut79p85esmakqzv/CM.html?dl=0